# Проверка пользовательского ввода на соответсвие маске

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как проверить что введенная пользователем информация соответствует следующей маске ввода:

Информация разбита на четыре подгруппы в качестве разделителя используется символ `-` в каждой подгруппе могут быть символы английского алфавита в различном регистре и цифры, например `w34p-TdhO-8ZpC-zWpO`

как на js будет выглядеть валидация данного условия? нужен только такой формат.

Comment: и что же это за формат? Вы бы расписали более подробно, а то мало того что выглядит как *сделайте за меня* так еще и не понятно что сделать

Comment: @Bald56rus к примеру это купон, что не понятного? это так и выглядит, я не знаю как это сделать, потому и спросил

Comment: *w34p* первая группа на первом месте может быть символ в нижнем регистре английского алфавита, потом идет 2 цифры и опять символ английского алфавита ну и т.п.

Comment: @Bald56rus только цифры и буквы любого регистра, но их 4 и потом "-", потом опять 4  цифры и буквы любого регистра и "-"... и т.д. 
финальный формат примерно такой как я написал: w34p-TdhO-8ZpC-zWpO

Comment: попытался переписать Ваш вопрос на что то более понятное

Comment: @Bald56rus спасибо большое за помощь) я просто думал это и так понятно, в след. раз задам вопрос более профессионально

Answer (score 1):

Вот регулярка:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Za-z0-9]{4}$
```

Вот вам небольшой пример в js.
http://jsfiddle.net/zaebiz/utezhj2o/

Если хотите валидировать непосредственно input, используйте его атрибут pattern с приведенным выше регулярным выражением.

Comment: спасибо большое) @nikita

Comment: @nikita Есть сервисы специально для написания и проверки регулярных выражений. Например - https://regex101.com/. Пользуйтесь)